# IdentitySever4 user claims and ASP.NET User.Identity

Tags: identityserver4

I've written a small IdentityServer demo server, following the examples in the documentation. I have the following `TestUser`:

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "1",
    Username = "Username",
    Password = "password",
    Claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, "Username"),
        new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email, "username@domain.com")
    }
}
```

I get an access token using `ResourceOwnerPassword` flow. And I am authorized to access my API.

The problem is that when in my protected API I'm trying to get the user identity, the name property is returned as null, and I don't see the email claim. No matter what I do I always see the same 12 claims. The `sub` claim is the only one passed with the information I put in the `Client` object.

How can I populate the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` property and send additional claims/data about the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason probably is that you are not requesting the proper resources/scopes for your client.

1. You need to define an API resource with the claims you need in the access token.

e.g in Resources.cs you can add the claims to be included in all api2 scopes

```
        new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "api2",

                ApiSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                UserClaims =
                {
                    JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                    JwtClaimTypes.Email
                },

                Scopes =
                {
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "api2.full_access",
                        DisplayName = "Full access to API 2",
                    },
                    new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "api2.read_only",
                        DisplayName = "Read only access to API 2"
                    }
                }
            }
```

2. Then you allow your resource owner client the access to those API resources.

e.g in client.cs

```
        new Client
            {
                ClientId = "roclient",
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    "custom.profile",
                    "api1", "api2.read_only"
                }
            },
```

3. You can then request the scope in your roclient

   ```
    client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("bob", "bob", "api2.read_only", optional).Result
   ```
4. Post the access token to the API and you will get the claims you added to your API resource.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the call to `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`, or wherever you're trying to use the token, make sure you set the `TokenValidationParameters` for the Name property to `ClaimTypes.Name`.

By default, the `Name` claim type is set to `name` (`JwtClaimType.Name`).
[image]

Comment: I don't understand where to put this. On the API side? on the Auth Server side?

Comment: Just for clarification, I'm setting up identity server like this: `app.UseIdentityServer();`

Comment: I found that if on my API I set the options for `UseIdentityServerAuthentication` to `NameClaimType = "sub"` I'm getting the name populated with what's in my subject. So the problem is that the claims I send to the user are not reflected in the API.